# Problem with implementing \ifcsname ... \endcsname into a custom macro

Tags: macros, tutorials, csname

I apologise in advance if this is a bad question but I have been trying to read up macros in Latex with the TeX-book but I just cannot work out why this doesn't work.

So I have a 'working' macro (pasted below) which lets you wrap `\ans{<answer>}` around answers in a tutorial sheet to save the answer to an 'array' of sorts; the answers in the array are then used to create an answer sheet with the command `\s`.
'Working' macro code:

```
        \titleformat{\section}{\titlerule\vspace{1mm}\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{2em}{}
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{{\noindent\hrulefill}\\ Problem \arabic{section}.} 
    %%%%%%%Each problem label generated with \section{}



    \newcounter{Questionpart}[section]
    \newcommand{\Qpart}{(\stepcounter{Questionpart}\alph{Questionpart})
        \global\expandafter\def\csname Prob\the\value{section}\endcsname{\the\value{Questionpart}}
        }
    %%%An attempt to count the parts in each problem but \csname Prob<number> \endcsname doesnt work with \foreach \y in {1,...,\csname Prob<number> \endcsname}
    %%%%%Parts a),b).....e), generated by \Qpart.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%Command of interest%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                
    \long\def\ans#1{
            \expandafter\global\expandafter\def\csname ans\the\value{section}\the\value{Questionpart} \endcsname{\item\quad#1}
            #1
            }%An 'array' structure which names each element as ans<problem_number><problem_part_in_numbers>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \newcommand{\p}[1]{
            \csname ans#1 \endcsname
    }%lets \s call the elements in the 'array'

    \newcommand{\s}{\newpage
            \begin{center}
                \Large\textbf{Solutions}
            \end{center}
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\value{section}}
            {
               \textbf{Problem \x}\par
               \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
               \foreach \y in {1,...,10}
    %couln't count the parts in a problem so set to 10 as a general size.
               {\p{\x\y}\par
               }
               \end{enumerate}
         }
    }
```

ISSUE:

I would like to implement a concatenate feature to the `\ans{}` command so that each `\ans{}` in the same Problem part will add together to create a full answer.
(sometimes it may be a 'prove that' question and the key points are spread out)

I tried something like this (which didn't work):

```
\makeatletter
    \long\def\ans#1{% if \DP@#1 is defined append to it otherwise create it
      \if\csname ans\the\value{section}\endcsname
        \edef\DP@tmp{\csname ans\the\value{section}\endcsname,#1}%
      \else
        \edef\DP@tmp{#1}%
      \fi
      \global\expandafter\let\csname ans\the\value{section}\endcsname\DP@tmp
    #1
    } 
    \makeatother
```

I will greatly appreciate help or any pointers.

Comment: `\if\csname` and `\ifcsname` are very different!

Comment: `\if\csname ans\the\value{section}\endcsname` compares the first two characters in the expansion of  the macro you might write informally as `\ans1`  and is true if they are the same.